# Open Outlook from SSRS to Add Multiple Email in CC from IE 10 Browser after Deploying to Report Sever

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services

I need to add multiple Email Address (sometimes 67 and sometimes 100+ to be added in cc) and they are generated dynamically when SSRS report is generated based on filters after deploying to report server. i am using "Mailto:" expresion with "?cc" & field!Email.value but when i click on link of email to open in outlook it does not add all the email as IE max URL limit is 2k so it is like MailTo:1@c.com;2@c.com;3@c.com;....;75@c.com; in url of IE so i would like to know is there any way to add all the email address in cc in outlook. i dont want to create group for email as it is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the URL Length limit for `mailto:` URLs is 512 bytes. No, there's no workaround for this; if you want to send a longer message from the client, you'd need to use an ActiveX control and have it call the Mail API (MAPI) directly.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for that amount of emails is setting up a global distribution list through the company. For example instead of having To: 67 emails CC: 100+ emails. Create mailing_group_department_dl@company.com "dl" meaning distribution list, "department" can be different based on audience and you can reason which email to use with if else statements etc based on parameters chosen.

The mailing group distribution email would be managed from a different location so you can add/remove people as needed.

If you don't have that option within the company, try something similar.